# SQL Group by between dates?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I cant seem to get a group by query to work with a date range.
CreationDate example value looks like 9/16/2013 1:57:55 PM

Is there a way using the query below to get the count of each processtype that is between 1/1/20 and 12/31/20?

```
SELECT COUNT(Id), ProcessType, CreationDate
FROM tblTest
WHERE date(CreationDate) BETWEEN "2020-01-01" AND "2020-12-31"
GROUP BY ProcessType
```

Comment: Double quotes (`"`) are the ANSI delimiter identifier for **columns**. Literal strings should be wrapped in single quotes (`'`).

Comment: Also, have a read of [Cast to date is sargable but is it a good idea?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea). TL;DR: No. Use explicit date boundaries with `>=` and `<`.

Comment: Remove CreationDate from the SELECT

Comment: I have the error date is not recognized as a built in function name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are actually a couple of things wrong here.

Notice that we changed the BETWEEN to `>=` and `<` and removed the `CreationDate` from the SELECT

```
SELECT COUNT(Id), ProcessType
FROM tblTest
WHERE CreationDate >= '2020-01-01' 
  AND CreationDate <  '2022-01-01"
GROUP BY ProcessType
```

Comment: @user1342164 Always happy to help

Comment: Perfect, the condition `CreationDate < first_day_after_end_date` ensures that times up to but excluding midnight are taken into account for the last day.

Answer (score 2):

The only problem I can see is that you don't include all your dimensions in the `group by` statement.
As for the error you describe in your later comment, I see that you use SQL Server from the tag of the post. SQL Server does not have the `date()` function built in ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#DateandTimeFunctions)).

You could try using another date function available in the source I linked that would better match your needs, or convert the Creation Date to a datetime format.